# Drools: Rule Compilation error - cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, drools

I am having trouble compiling a simple rule in drools. I have analysed the code and cannot figure out what's wrong. It might have to do with the "or" condition tho.

```sh
rule "Generic AC1" 
    when 
        $product : Product(canonicalId == "Product AC1") from listOfCompatibleProducts 
        or DateRangeValidator($verifyDate : validationDate, ($verifyDate.compareTo(DateUtils.parseDate("1970-01-01 01:00:00.000")) < 1) || ($verifyDate.compareTo(DateUtils.parseDate("4892-10-07 22:52:48.547")) > 0)) 
    then 
        System.out.println("DEBUG: ENGINE has fired Generic AC1"); 
        listOfCompatibleProducts.remove($product); 
end;
```

I get the following error:

```
One or more rules are invalid: 
ERROR - Rule Compilation error $product cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that Drools will split your `or` into 2 separate rules:

```
rule "Generic AC1 1" 
    when 
        $product : Product(canonicalId == "Product AC1") from listOfCompatibleProducts         
    then 
        System.out.println("DEBUG: ENGINE has fired Generic AC1"); 
        listOfCompatibleProducts.remove($product); 
end

rule "Generic AC1 2" 
    when 
        DateRangeValidator($verifyDate : validationDate, ($verifyDate.compareTo(DateUtils.parseDate("1970-01-01 01:00:00.000")) < 1) || ($verifyDate.compareTo(DateUtils.parseDate("4892-10-07 22:52:48.547")) > 0)) 
    then 
        System.out.println("DEBUG: ENGINE has fired Generic AC1"); 
        listOfCompatibleProducts.remove($product); 
end;
```

As you can see, in the second rule's RHS, you are trying to use a `$product` variable that is not defined in its LHS.

Hope it helps,